# Array push with multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this multidimentional array:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["service"]=>
    string(3) "top"
  }
}
```

and I want to push to the inner array the string below

```
string(3) "443"
```

the string above I got it from an array using array_shift

```
$id = array_shift($_POST['updateIDs']);
```

so it can become like this:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["service"]=>
    string(3) "top"
    ['id']=>'443'
  }
}
```

I think it must be done with array_push and foreach...i tried but I could not.

Comment: For what you have posted, `$arr[0]['id'] = '443';` will do what you want. But perhaps you want something more general?

Comment: Please add a bit more context to this very basic question.  Does your original array ever have more than one element?  If not, why add the extra level.  If it can have multiple rows of data, will you be repeating the element-push with additional values from `$_POST`?

Comment: You should consider adding details so I can adapt my answer to fullfil your exact needs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try :

```
$array = [['service' => 'top']];
$id = '443';

foreach ($array as &$value) {
    $value['id'] = $id;
}

var_dump($array);
```

The thing is, if you have more entries, it will append the same value to all occurences.

But I don't know what is your context, with more details I can adapt this code

As @mickmamusa's comment says : Why the extra level ?

If you can remove it so the code to push id become simply

```
$array = ['service' => 'top'];
$id = '443';

$array['id'] = $id;

var_dump($array);
```

The foreach is my prefered choice to when you have multi-dimmensional array to handle some case depends on the current key. So I usually prefer not to use this kind of code :

```
$array[0]["id"] = '443';
```

Comment: why have you declared `$key`?  You are modifying a copy.  This answer is incorrect (obviously untested)

Comment: more general approched due to my last sentence, i don't know what is his context

Comment: `$yourArray[$key]["id"] = $id ;` will do that :P

Comment: @mickmackusa edited. You've right, it was a copy, now i use a reference modification

Comment: @Hooli Fringe case is: if the original array has two rows, you will be performing two element pushes.  This OP is very light on the details.  You should explain how your answer works

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$array[0]['id'] = '443';
```

or

```
<?php
reset($array);
$key = key($array);
$array[$key]['id'] = '443';
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low value on StackOverflow.  Please always post some explanation with every answer that you post (even if they are incredibly basic)